# Why is zinc sulfate used in daniell cell

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, ions, electricity

Why is zinc sulfate needed in the construction of a daniell cell.  It seems that because the zinc is getting oxidized and not reduced there is no need to have a solution of zinc sulfate as it will produced when the zinc is reduced.  The sulfate ions would simply cross the salt bridge and balance out the charges.

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Zinc sulfate is not needed. With any other neutral salt in its place, your cell will work just fine.

Without *any* salt at all, though, it will not work, since pure water is a poor conductor of electric current.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I do not actually see how I could provide an answer (in the strict sense) to the question, when the question itself relies on a wrong presumption. Why does a cat bark, really?

Comment: If you have doubts about the premise of the question, it is better to ask for clarification in a comment.

Comment: I do have doubts about many other questions, but this one is crystal clear. Also, if we clarify it, wouldn't the question vanish into nothing?

Anyway, I'll follow your advice the next time.